# Magento admin store scope

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, acl

Is it possible for a multi-website Magento CE 1.7.0.2 installation to limit access to admin users by website?

Are there any good modules which handle this functionality if it doesn't exists?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is only included in Magento Enterprise Edition.
I don't know if there are any working 3rd party extensions.